# Get mean of numpy array using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame where one column is a `numpy` array of numbers. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'data': [np.array([0.43, 0.32, 0.19]),
             np.array([0.41, 0.11, 0.21]),
             np.array([0.94, 0.35, 0.14]),
             np.array([0.78, 0.92, 0.45]),
             np.array([0.32, 0.63, 0.48]),
             np.array([0.17, 0.12, 0.15]),
             np.array([0.54, 0.12, 0.16]),
             np.array([0.48, 0.16, 0.19]),
             np.array([0.14, 0.47, 0.01])]
})
```

I want to `groupby` the id column and aggregate by taking the element-wise average of the array. Splitting the array up first is not feasible since it is length 300 and I have 200,000+ rows. When I do `df.groupby('id').mean()`, I get the error "No numeric types to aggregate". I am able to get an element-wise mean of the lists using `df['data'].mean()`, so I think there should be a way to do a grouped mean. To clarify, I want the output to be an array for each value of ID. Each element in the resulting array should be the mean of the values of the elements in the corresponding position within each group. In the example, the result should be:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'id': [1, 2,3,4],
    'data': [np.array([0.42, 0.215, 0.2]),
             np.array([0.86, 0.635, 0.29500000000000004]),
             np.array([0.3433333333333333, 0.29, 0.26333333333333336]),
             np.array([0.31, 0.315, 0.1])]
})
```

Could someone suggest how I might do this? Thanks!

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mean it twice, one at array level and once at group level:

```
df['data'].map(np.mean).groupby(df['id']).mean().reset_index()
```

---

```
   id      data
0   1  0.278333
1   2  0.596667
2   3  0.298889
3   4  0.241667
```

Based on comment, you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['data'].tolist(),index=df['id']).mean(level=0).agg(np.array,1)

id
1                                 [0.42, 0.215, 0.2]
2                 [0.86, 0.635, 0.29500000000000004]
3    [0.3433333333333333, 0.29, 0.26333333333333336]
4                                 [0.31, 0.315, 0.1]
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
df.groupby("id")['data'].apply(np.mean)
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, I want the output to be an array (in the example it would be length four), where each element is the mean of the elements in that position.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes it does but with `np.mean` in my version, just tested and edited :-) only mean gives me `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: `Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated` Should be `pd.DataFrame(df['data'].tolist(),index=df['id']).groupby(level=0).mean().agg(np.array,1)` for Future versions.

Answer (score 2):

First, splitting up the array *is* feasible because your current storage requires storing a complex object of all the values within a DataFrame. This is going to take a lot more space than simply storing the flat 2D array

```
# Your current memory usage
df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
1352

# Create a new DataFrame (really just overwrite `df` but keep separate for illustration)
df1 = pd.concat([df['id'], pd.DataFrame(df['data'].tolist())], 1)
#   id     0     1     2
#0   1  0.43  0.32  0.19
#1   1  0.41  0.11  0.21
#2   2  0.94  0.35  0.14
#3   2  0.78  0.92  0.45
#4   3  0.32  0.63  0.48
#5   3  0.17  0.12  0.15
#6   3  0.54  0.12  0.16
#7   4  0.48  0.16  0.19
#8   4  0.14  0.47  0.01
```

Yes, this looks bigger, but it's not in terms of memory, it's actually smaller. The 3x factor here is a bit extreme, for larger DataFrames with long arrays it will probably be like 95% of the memory. Still it *has* to be less.

```
df1.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
#416
```

And now your aggregation is a normal `groupby` + `mean`, columns give the location in the array

```
df1.groupby('id').mean()
#           0      1         2
#id                           
#1   0.420000  0.215  0.200000
#2   0.860000  0.635  0.295000
#3   0.343333  0.290  0.263333
#4   0.310000  0.315  0.100000
```

Comment: Awesome. I am guessing here but I think keeping id as index instead of concat might save some space. We can then refer to the level when grouping

Comment: @anky, not sure about the memory and index, I haven't ever looked into it. Sadly the `mean(level=)` is deprecated because it seems like they're on a warpath to simplify the pandas api and remove all of the redundant ways to do the same operation (r.i.p. lookup :( ), so you'll still need `.groupby('id').mean()` (good think `id` can be in the index at least)

Answer (score 1):

Group by mean for array where output is array of mean value

```
 df['data'].map(np.array).groupby(df['id']).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id                                             data
0   1                               [0.42, 0.215, 0.2]
1   2               [0.86, 0.635, 0.29500000000000004]
2   3  [0.3433333333333333, 0.29, 0.26333333333333336]
3   4                               [0.31, 0.315, 0.1]
```

Comment: What is your pandas version, I am getting `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` when I run this in `'1.1.3'`

Comment: pandas==1.3.2  numpy==1.21.2

Comment: This is interesting as it is similar to my first answer but produces a different output. Cant say what pandas is changing with every version :/

Answer (score 1):

You can always `.apply` the numpy mean.

```
df.groupby('id')['data'].apply(np.mean).apply(np.mean)

# returns:
id
1    0.278333
2    0.596667
3    0.298889
4    0.241667
Name: data, dtype: float64
```